# Can I use Maximum likelihood estimation method to estimate a Box-Jenkins model?

Tags: systems-of-equations, parameter-estimation, least-squares, maximum-likelihood, system-identification

I have the known measurement: Noise $e(t)$, output $y(k)$, input $u(k)$.

I need to find the Box-Jenkins model:

$$y[k] = \frac{B(q)}{F(q)}u[k] + \frac{C(q)}{D(q)}e[k]$$

Where $B, F, C, D$ are polynomial expressions. Eg.:

$B(q) = 1 + b_1q^{-1} \dots  b_nq^{-n}$

Often I have used least square $Ax=b$ to find the parameters inside the polynomial expressions. But in this case, it seems not to work for me.

I have heard that in order to estimate the parameters inside the polynomial, Maximum likelihood estimation must be applied for finding the parameters inside this equation

$$F(q)D(q)y[k] = B(q)D(q)u[k] + F(q)C(q)e[k]$$

How would you do?

[image]

Comment: Are all four polynomials unknown?

Comment: Yes. All four are unkown.

Comment: I do not think LS will work here otherwise than what you tried with $a(q)y[k]=b(q)u[k]+c(q)e[k]$, but then you won't be able to separate (factor) $a,b,c$ into $B,C,D,F$ because they will be likely coprime polynomials. Any attempts to enforce exact common zeros in $a,b,c$ will make the optimization nonconvex. You may try some kind of model reduction on $b/a$ and $c/a$ to reduce the system order.

Comment: @A.Γ. How about maximum likelihood method? That won't work either? Finding the solution by using numerical tools?

Comment: Any more suggestions how to solve this?